# Nested Elements with wildcard selector / Event Bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind to an element and add an outline to it when I over it. The problem is that when I hover over a nested element, the parent elements are also selected.

When I hover over "5 deep" I should only have a border around that span and not all of its parents.

http://jsfiddle.net/7uQwr/

How can I avoid this? Kind of an odd use case, but I dont have control over the markup here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because `event` is bubbled until the `body` element. Stop the event propagation using `event.stopPropagation()` then it will restrict only to the element on which the event is triggered.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7uQwr/1/)**

Comment: In the callback handler make sure you have passed `e`.

Comment: If you drag left to right across the text it doesn't behave well.

Comment: That is because the elements are placed in such a way that when you mouse over from left to right the mouse out event of element is not fired. I think you want this take a look http://jsfiddle.net/7uQwr/4/

Comment: @texasCode - Did you take a look at this?

Comment: Yes Sir! Thanks for the insight + answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="1">
one deep
<span id="2">
    two deep
    <span id="3">
        Three deep
        <span id="4">
            Four Deep
            <span id="5">
                five deep
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>

 $('#5').hover(function() {
     $(this).css('outline', '2px solid red');
    }, 
      function() {
        $(this).css('outline', 'none')
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work with `hover`. If you moused left to right or vice versa it did not behave the way I think you want it to. Instead I did this which seems to work well.

http://jsfiddle.net/7uQwr/6/

```
$('body *').mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).css('outline', '2px solid red');  
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body *').mouseout(function(e) {
    $('span').css('outline', 'none');
});
```